# TCA type depending on if relation is given or not

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I have 3 tables:

- item
- country
- region

region is an irre-field in country.
In item i want to have an selectbox where you can choose a country and only if this country has regions there shall appear a new selectbox with the regions related to the country.

If the countries were fix i could use `$TCA['item']['ctrl']['type'] = 'country';` and `$TCA['item']['types']` to reload the backend and display the region selectbox if needed.

Is there any possibility in doing this with a non-fix country list checking if it has relations?

An option to hide the region-field if it has no options would solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this is not easily possible. You can of course create a USER element and implement the logic yourself.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html

You could also play around with the "type" column property from the `ctrl` section, but it sounds you already tried this.